# Can you enumerate the set of all words over a finite alphabet?

Tags: complexity-theory, regular-languages

Can you enumerate the set of all words over a finite alphabet?

Comment: What are your thoughts about this ? How would you generate all words from 'a' ? From 'ab' ? From 'abc' ?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the original poster wanted to point out that lexicographic order does not work for the purpose of enumerating all words.

1
11
111
1111
...

and you never reach 2 (and you miss 0).

Of course, as pointed out by [user253751](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/24082/user253751), numeric order works.  For example, the set of all numbers can be enumerated over the alphabet 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

That is a psychologic problem: we have difficulty in recognizing that letters and digits are the same kind, though literature and mathematics may not be.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The set of words of length $l$ is made of all strings of length $l-1$ appended with one of the letters.

Check that

- they are all different,
- none is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. One way is to enumerate all the words of length 0 (if you consider them words), then all the words of length 1, then all the words of length 2, and so on.

Obviously, the set is infinite, so the enumeration never ends, but every word is enumerated at a finite step in the process.